# Is it normal to get different answers in different versions of GAMS?

Tags: gams-math

I solved a model with two different versions of GAMS.  (Version 24.2 and Version 27.3)

The answers I get from Version 24.2 are different from the answers from Version 27.3 !
Is this normal? 
Which answer can be trusted?

Thanks!

Comment: This depends on many different factors and cannot be answered completely w/o more information: Is it an optimal solution? Did you hit any limits (e.g. time or iteration)? What kind of problem do you have (linear? non-linear? convex? non-convex?), ... Even in the "simplest case" (optimal solution for linear model), there can be more than one correct solution (objective value is the same, but other variables might differ).

Comment: Hi @Lutz I had MIP Model , in both version the statue was Optimal, but objective value was diffrent!

Comment: So if it was a MIP model, I guess it was optimal within certain tolerances, right? It can easily happen, that the solution is different (but should still be at least "similiar") between different versions. Most likely, the version of the solver you used was different between the two versions and behaves a little different.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this with a MIP model. Actually, I obtained different optimal objective values (in the optimality) when running it with different solvers or declaring variables in a different order without changing anything in the model. This erratic behavior can happen when you have numerical issues, which can be a consequence of a large matrix coefficient range, for example.

If this is the case, first you should try to reformulate your model (see an useful guideline here: [Guidelines for Numerical Issues](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/guidelines_for_numerical_i.html)).

If reformulating is not possible or not enough to solve the issue,  my suggestion is changing the solver resolution options. Some solvers such as Gurobi and CPLEX have options that help dealing with numerical issues (e.g. numericfocus, scaleflag, etc. for Gurobi). You should look for the respective helpful options according to the solver you are using.